# rotate an an embedded game 90 degrees

Tags: html, rotation

I am trying to rotate this embed code 90 degrees, can you please help me out

```
<div class="miniclip-game-embed" data-game-name="8-ball-pool-multiplayer" data-theme="0" data-width="750" data-height="520" data-language="en"><a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/">Play 8 Ball Pool</a></div>
```

Play 8 Ball Pool / More Sports games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS style to your div:

```
style='transform: rotate(90deg);'
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer but can you show me how to do so on the code below:<div class="miniclip-game-embed" data-game-name="8-ball-pool-multiplayer" data-theme="0" data-width="750" data-height="520" data-language="en"><a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/">Play 8 Ball Pool</a></div>
<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/" target="_blank">Play 8 Ball Pool</a> / More <a href="http://www.miniclip.com/games/genre-3/" target="_blank">Sports games</a></p>

Comment: <div style='transform: rotate(90deg);' class="miniclip-game-embed" data-game-name="8-ball-pool-multiplayer" data-theme="0" data-width="750" data-height="520" data-language="en"><a href="miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/">Play 8 Ball Pool</a></div> <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="miniclip.com/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/"; target="_blank">Play 8 Ball Pool</a> / More <a href="miniclip.com/games/genre-3/"; target="_blank">Sports games</a></p>

Comment: i copied your script but it didnt work i dont know why

Comment: now it works thanks alot

Comment: i really appreciate your help